# Let's not [delay] this burnination!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Ran across the [delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delay) tag today. It seems like a meta tag, especially given its laconic wiki description.
Lets go through the criteria:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, this tag is ambiguous. Specifically it fails to differentiate between specific sleep-like function calls and the higher level unresponsiveness of a ui or system. In addition, even if it were scoped to only deal with the former, it is not language specific, so it would still be too broad.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Mostly, both sleep-like function calls and unresponsiveness are indeed characteristics specific to programming.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. There are many causes of a delay in a system, and they are likely to have many different causes and resolutions. The addition of this tag does not help differentiate a question.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Absolutely not. As mentioned, a delay question could be about system responsiveness, both in a ui or system level manner as well as being about purposeful delay calls, like sleep. It could even be used to describe network delay, ie lag.

**Harmfulness**

The last, overarching criterion is whether this tag is actively harmful. I'm not sure it is. However, I do think that the individual concepts present in this tag could better served through more specific tags.

**Use**

Additionally, I notice is that there is a fair bit of use of this tag.
There are almost four thousand [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delay) using the tag. So that has to factor into things as well.

**Experts**

There are no gold badge members for this tag. There aren't any ['experts'](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delay/topusers) — one person has answered 18 questions, another 10, but everyone else has answered 4 or fewer questions.  One person has asked 4 questions; everyone else has asked 2 or 1.

**My Suggested usage**

So I went through the two hundred or so questions that used this tag and categorized them into several groups classified by whether I think they should be using this tag. Arduino, pygame, C# and flutter have an explicit function called "delay", so they're the closest to being correct. I'd edit this directly into the tag wiki but the edit queue is full or something.

| Usage | Tag to use |
| --- | --- |
| Delay of execution in [arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) | This |
| Delay of execution in [pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pygame) | This |
| Delay of execution in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) | This or possibly [thread-sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-sleep) |
| Delay of execution in [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) | This |
| Delay of execution in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) | [sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sleep) |
| Regularly spaced delays of execution | [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timer) |
| Network delay | [lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lag) |
| Unexpected slowness of execution | [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimization) or [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) |
| Delay between electronic pulses | Likely [pwm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pwm), make sure the question isn't about general hardware |
| [Delay differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) | [differential-equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/differential-equations) |
| Pause in media playback | Do not add this tag |
| Unresponsive User interface | Do not add this tag |

Additionally, the following related tags are probably ambiguous as well:
[wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wait)[resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resume)[until-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/until-loop)[timedelay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timedelay)[lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lag)[delayed-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delayed-execution)

Comment: I don't agree with this. It's doesn't seem to be causing any harm.

Comment: It's a useless tag, but we have [hordes] of those.  And with a count of 3,846 questions, it's going to be more trouble to remove than it is worth.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, I agree that there are many of those. If there are trouble to remove them, do we need a better handling of those? Could we have a feature to e.g. not allow "those tags" to be used on new questions?

Comment: @jonas: The procedure put in place for handing tag burninations is so overwrought that it's only tractable for the most severe of cases.  Blacklisting further use of tags can only be done at the developer level, and that process does not scale well.  You could try a "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" admonition in the Tag Excerpt, but people routinely ignore these.

Comment: And at the end of the day, it really doesn't matter all that much whether the tag is used or not.

Comment: Seems like burnination is not quite the course of action preferred here. If there is consensus that the tag is ambiguous but not causing harm, I think the best way forward is for me to edit the tag wiki to include suggestions on alternate tags for the different subuses.

Comment: This tag is too general (as the OP showed) and does not help in differentiating questions. It helps link together posts that should not be linked at all.

Comment: @code11 The question would benefit from suggesting alternate tags to be used instead, if [tag:delay] gets burninated.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Good suggestion. I'll see if I can edit that in when I have the time. I know [wait] [sleep] and [thread-sleep] exist, off the top of my head.

Comment: [sleep] and [thread-sleep] are at least useful in the sense that they are well-defined, well-understood concepts in several programming languages.  [wait] is useless.

Comment: Blacklisting isn't done anymore, even at the developer level. It's been explained to me that it's too much of a performance issue. I guess if we were going to make it happen, there would have to be a *really* good reason. A "useless" tag isn't enough of a reason.

Comment: Are people disagreeing with a burnination that even if approved they aren't going to participate, because they don't want to participate... what? If you don't want to participate, just don't participate in the discussion. If it's too CSPAN boring job, just ignore this.

Comment: I dislike having [sleep] and [thread-sleep]. The concept for both is the same and eventually is all comes down to the OS thread scheduling.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't disagree. I picked those tags because thread-sleep is, according to its wiki, explicitly about the .net Thread sleep. Its well scoped. Sleep on the other hand is just as broad as delay right now but I thought it best for C since its an exact word match for the function.

Comment: I think [delay] is better than [sleep]. You can delay without using sleep.

Comment: FWIW "sleep" is a function in python, aka `time.sleep`.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a burnination request. Just a tag clarification and retagging effort.

Comment: @CodyGray Wow, so failure to add basic and required features to the platform is now due to "performance issues"? I wonder how many more creative excuses SE Inc. can come up with to justify doing nothing.

Comment: Technically there are 3 kinds of delays: busy-wait, CPU effective sleep or misc timer based delays using software or hardware timers. Those 3 categories should cover all manner of systems.

Comment: Also back in the days when dinosaurs roamed the earth, MS DOS API had a function named `delay`. (It was a busy-wait because MS DOS wasn't a multitasking OS.) Doubt there are many questions about that one though.

Comment: @Lundin actually, I *did* run into some DOS delay questions! The smaller categories of only a few questions I didn't add for brevity's sake.

Comment: @Bergi Correct, in hindsight. Based on feedback, it seems that people agree that the tag is ambiguous and lacks guidance, but that it is not causing harm.

Comment: @code11 Ah, I had not seen the edit history

Comment: I think we might need a tag for [animation delays](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelay%5D+animation). Also there are [[tag:delayed-execution]] and [[tag:timedelay]] tags that we should cover here.

Comment: *There are no gold badge members for this tag.* There are two.

Comment: @AdrianMole Is that true? I couldn't not find anyone via https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold. I also expected for the [gold badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/10218/delay) to be valid if there were any. Definitely could have over looked something though.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delay/topusers

Comment: @AdrianMole gold badge needs 1000 score and 200 answers if I'm not mistaken, no user in that list has 200 answers.

Comment: @Braiam Ah - Very good point. I just looked at the scores. I squat corrected.

Answer (score 5):

A cursory glance to this tag I've found that **it could be removed from the system with a Community Manager assistance**. The people that "answers" the tag, mainly answer other tags that were just tacked [delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delay) because in some point the question said that. The user with most answers from the all time top answerers, Nick Craver, is basically answering jQuery questions (18 of all the +4k has both tags). That would only leave the questions with only this tag... which I didn't find any (from again, cursory glance).

So, lets stop delaying and elevate this request.

Comment: Having someone at corporate push the big red button is a much better idea than trying to remove it through the burdensome and bureaucratic process we now have, despite your protestations of "if you don't like the process, then simply don't participate."

Comment: @RobertHarvey My protest is that users seems against the burnination at all, just because they don't like to participate in it, not by the tags merits alone. In other words, you aren't going to even do the job, why are you against anyone trying to do it?